# How do I make Paypal's checkout process happen in a small popup?

Tags: paypal

The Humble Frozenbyte Bundle recently ended.  Before it did, if you tried to pay for the bundle by clicking their Paypal button, a small popup window appeared, asked you to log in to PayPal, asked you to click "Yes this is the right amount to pay", and the popup closed again.  Excellent!

I'd like to do the same thing with my application, but **I can't figure out the correct Paypal flow to use**.  The standard cmd=_xclick WPS checkout flow takes up the entire screen, so I know that's not what Humble Bundle put in their popup...

To be clear, I'm not asking how to make a popup window in HTML.  I'm asking how to access a PayPal checkout flow that can **fit in a small popup window**, about 400x800 if I remember correctly.  If the Humble Bundle were still open I'd just look at the source code, of course!

Thanks in advance for any tips!

**Update**: PayPal Digital Goods are what I was looking for.

The (not very good) Paypal integration guide is here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide_DG.pdf

And the blogpost that I am following to try to get this working is here: https://www.x.com/blogs/matt/2011/02/15/another-digital-goods-demo

I haven't quite gotten it working yet, but it's getting me close.

Answer (score -2):

The guide you are referencing for digital goods now includes an Integration Wizard.

https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

This wizard includes 
Express Checkout PayPal
Express Checkout - Digital goods
Express Checkout PayFlow Edition
Credit Card PayFlow